# How to get user's region on Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I want to download a website's content based on user's current region. For that I need country code like `US` , `FR` etc.. How to get that?

**I tried these:**

this always shows US. I think it comes from app manifest.

```
var region = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion;
```

and this:

```
var cultureName = new DateTimeFormatter("longdate", new[] { "US" }).ResolvedLanguage;

return new CultureInfo(cultureName);
```

this works. returns something like `en-US` which I can extract country code from it. but sometimes it may return only language `en` without country code.

How to get system's current two character country code? thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that lots of people set US on the device setting but they aren't inside the US

Comment: @Quincy yes I'm aware of it. That's not a problem for my case, their choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get user's home region setting, we can use  [GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences#Windows_System_UserProfile_GlobalizationPreferences_HomeGeographicRegion) property.

```
// Obtain the user's home geographic region.
var region = Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion;
```

The home region is usually set when Windows is installed and is available in
**Settings → Time & language → Region & language → Country or region**.

[Windows.Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization) also has a [GeographicRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion) object that is provided as a helper object. It lets apps inspect details about a particular region, such as its display name, native name, and currencies in use.

```
// Get the user's geographic region and its two-letter identifier for this region.
var geographicRegion = new Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion();
var code = geographicRegion.CodeTwoLetter;
```

For more info, please see [Manage language and region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/manage-language-and-region).

Comment: Thank you very much.. very useful